# Order Results By Occurrence

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, popularity

I have the following two tables.

BookmarkTag ( BookmarkID, TagID )
Tag ( TagID, Title)

Currently I am selecting all the tags with the appropriate BookmarkID. The problem is I want to only select the tag once to avoid duplication in the result and also only bring back the tags that occur the most.

This is my current SQL query:

```
SELECT Tag.Title 
FROM `Tag` INNER JOIN BookmarkTag 
WHERE BookmarkTag.BookmarkID = 1 AND Tag.TagID = BookmarkTag.TagID'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the join condition in an `ON` clause after the `JOIN` keyword. **Not** in the `where` clause.
You were mixing SQL89 with SQL92 syntax. This may work I haven't tested, but this is faster.

```
SELECT Tag.Title 
FROM `Tag` t
INNER JOIN BookmarkTag b ON (t.tagid = b.tagid)
WHERE B.BookmarkID = 1
GROUP BY t.tagid
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

In order to make the results unique per tag, do a `group by` on tagid.
Then you can `order by` occurrence by using count(*) to see make the tags with the highest occurrence float to the top.
*(try to always use `count(*)` because it is faster than `count(afield)` )*

Comment: I get the following error: #1052 - Column 'tagid' in group statement is ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.Title, COUNT(*) AS TitleCount
FROM BookmarkTag AS bt
INNER JOIN Tag AS t ON t.TagID = bt.TagID
GROUP BY t.Title
ORDER BY TitleCount DESC
```

If You want to get a 7 most popular titles, add `LIMIT 7` at the end of query, or any other number. My version will generate all in descending order of their popularity.