# Mysql sortation on multiple LIKE's

Tags: mysql, sql-like

There are a lot of topics on sortation (like: [Order Results By Occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324338/order-results-by-occurrence)) but these are all for one value.

I have a search field that people use with keywords; simply said the queries generated look like:

1 word:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `meta` 
WHERE (`keywords` LIKE  '%bike%')
```

2 words:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `meta` 
WHERE (
`keywords` LIKE  '%bike%'
OR  `keywords` LIKE  '%yellow%'
)
```

etc...

What I would like to do is sort the result on the most found keywords. How would I do this for an unknown amount of `keywords LIKE's`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general way to sort by the number of keyword matches in MySQL (using `like`):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `meta` 
ORDER BY ((`keywords` LIKE  '%bike%') +
          (`keywords` LIKE  '%yellow%') +
          . . .
         ) desc;
```

If you want to handle a flexible number of keywords, then you should use an appropriate relational data structure.  Storing `keywords` in a single field (probably comma-separated) is not the best approach.  You should have a separate table with one row per keyword.

EDIT:

To add in the number of keywords found, the expression can be put in the `select` statement:

```
SELECT m.*,
       ((`keywords` LIKE  '%bike%') +
        (`keywords` LIKE  '%yellow%') +
        . . .
       ) as NumKeywordsFound
FROM `meta` m
ORDER BY NumKeywordsFound desc;
```

You can also add a `having` clause to specify that at least one is found:

```
SELECT m.*,
       ((`keywords` LIKE  '%bike%') +
        (`keywords` LIKE  '%yellow%') +
        . . .
       ) as NumKeywordsFound
FROM `meta` m
HAVING NumKeywordsFound > 1
ORDER BY NumKeywordsFound desc;
```

If you want to find the number of times a keyword is found in each expression:

```
 select m.*,
        length(replace(keywords, 'bike', 'bike1')) - length(keywords) as NumBikes,
        length(replace(keywords, 'yellow', 'yellow1')) - length(keywords) as NumYellows
FROM `meta` m
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks, is there also a possibility to receive the amount of keywords found? (bike 5 times, yellow 1 time etc)